# Correlation matrix shrinkage causes matrix multiplication error for monte carlo simulation

Tags: python, correlation, matrix-multiplication, pca, montecarlo

I have list of 10 stocks and a correlation 10x10 correlation matrix for these stocks. I have to reduce the size of this matrix to 3x3 and use it for Monte Carlo simulation to simulate possible outcomes. The problem is that reducing the size is causing the matrix multiplication to fail. How can I move forward ?

```
num_stocks = 10
correlation_matrix = np.zeros((num_stocks, num_stocks))
for i in range(num_stocks):
            for j in range(num_stocks):
                correlation_matrix[i, j] = 0.9 ** abs(i - j)

# using PCA to generate 3x3 reduced correlation matrix
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
p = pca.fit_transform(correlation_matrix)
reduced_correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(p, rowvar=False)

# Generate 10 random values for simulation
random_vars = np.random.normal(0, 1, num_stocks)

correlated_random_vars = random_vars @ reduced_correlation_matrix

# logic after this uses monte carlo simulation
# correlated_random_vars needs to be a list of 10 random variables
# failing above as random_vars is [10x1] matrix and reduced_correlation_matrix is [3x3] matrix
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have access to the underlying time series of the 10 stocks? or just the precomputed correlation matrix?

Comment: I have a present value of all 10 stocks which is set to $100. I have to simulate future pricing by using Monte Carlo simulation). In this model, I need random 10 values that get derived from correlation matrix, that is way I do (correlated_random_vars = random_vars @ reduced_correlation_matrix). I will use this correlated_random_vars to generate next simulated values of the 10 stocks. How to derive Correlation matrix is already in the code. Thanks.

Comment: To add to above, this is an interview question. I was given how to construct Correlation matrix first and it was successful simulating my next 10 correlated_random_vars to feed the Monte Carlo. Problem is in the second phase, I was asked to reduce the size of Correlation matrix to 3x3 using PCA and perform same simulation. But now dimensions for matrix multiplication for random_vars and new correlation_matrix do not match.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the clarification! So I guess there's a misunderstanding in how PCA works. You want to apply PCA to the stock data (not on the correlation matrix), then you take the first three PCs and compute the correlation matrix (3x3). Then when you generate a new random variable (10 stocks) you just transform them using your PCA model.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @nicrie. I have explicit instructions to reduce the correlation matrix to 3x3. However, you did give me a good consult. I would also run PCA on input stock values or do np.random.normal(0, 1, 3) instead of np.random.normal(0, 1, 10). The reason it should work is because I'm taking the mean of the simulated stock for value projections as the question directs. So Thank you.